# Are execution times proportional to number of rows?

Tags: mysql

I'm certain that the execution time is directly proportional to the number of rows in a MySQL query. My question is, in what proportion? Will the execution time of a query increase significantly as the database grows bigger or only a little?

Any info on the subject will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really.

A `select * from table` will take proportionally longer (if you have many rows, for a table with just four rows it will not take twice the time as for a table with two, this will be dominated by "fixed costs")

A `select * from table limit 10` will take the same amount of time, regardless of table size.

A `select count(*) from table` is instantaneous on MySQL, regardless of table size.

A `select * from table where primary_key = ?` will scale logarithmically (because a B-tree index is used).

A `select count(*) from table where non_indexed_column = ?` will take proportionally longer, but a `select count(*) from table where indexed_column = ?` won't.

A `select * from table_a join table_b` will take four times as long if the number of rows doubles. A `select * from table_a join table_b using (column_a = indexed_column_b)` should scale linearly.

A `select * from table_a order by unindexed_column` will take more than twice the time if the number of rows doubles. A `select * from table_a order by indexed_column` can scale proportionally, but a `select * from table_a where something = ? order by indexed_column` might not.

All operations take significantly more time as soon as the table no longer fits into memory. Or if you run the query at a time when the memory is used for other tables. This can be a real wall to hit, with execution times suddenly going through the roof.

Also, you were taking about "rows in the query" (rows selected) and "rows in the table". Both of these have an impact. The "existence" of deleted rows in the table can also have an impact.

Comment: Most DBMS do better than quadrupling the execution time for a join; only the most primitive nested loop joins would be that bad.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Added a comment about the availability of memory caching (which would indeed make a join - or anything else - significantly faster). Or slower, if things suddenly don't fit into memory anymore.

Comment: An equijoin on two tables with indexes on the join columns should be more or less linear as you scan the two indexes in parallel, comparing values as you go.  Because it uses indexes (without needing to read each data row), that can be quite efficient.  I don't know for sure that MySQL manages that, but I expect it does.

Comment: Yes, but my example was a cross-join. An equijoin will (should/can?) indeed scale linearly. Adding this too (but I think the point is being made already, the point being "it depends").

Comment: OK — given that you have no ON condition (is that allowed?), then it is a cross-join and it will take time proportional to the product of the table sizes (roughly, number of rows in each table).  And yes, the 'it depends' is crucial.  I can only give you one up-vote, I'm afraid (and you have that already).

Answer (score 0):

The biggest factor in execution time of SELECT queries is whether they require a complete scan of the database or can use an index. For the former case, the execution time grows as the database grows. For the latter, it does not (at least not significantly).

Answer (score 0):

Execution time is proportional to number of rows as well as number of columns, You'll have to put index keys to columns, from that columns you'll build query, that will run much more times fast!